Why am I getting "invalid_client: invalid client credentials" after upgrading from Android SDK 10.2.0 to 11.0.0?
I've inherited an Android app that uses the Salesforce SDK for auth. I've never used this SDK before.
For some time now, the app has been running against the 10.0.0 SDK with no problems signing in. I bumped from 10.0.0 to 10.1.0 and could still sign in.  I bumped from 10.1.0 to 10.2.0 and could still sign in.  However, when I bump from 10.2.0 to 11.0.0, and try to sign in I see a toast with the message: "invalid_client: invalid client credentials".
I've looked through the Salesforce migration information and I believe I've done everything I need to do.
What does this error mean and what can I do to resolve it?
Note: I do not have access to the Salesforce console so I cannot 100% confirm that the client id I am using is correct.  However, since this has been working, I am assuming it is.
Here is the minimal, reproducible and complete source code. This literally runs and reproduces the issue.
MainActivity.kt
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_onboarding.signInButton
import vml.aafp.app.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding)

        SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(applicationContext, this::class.java)
        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance()
                .clientManager
                .getRestClient(this) { }
        }
    }
}

App.kt (just for the record)
class App : Application() {
}

Not shown: an activity_onboarding.xml file and a bootconfig.xml file.
Not sure if it is useful information, but I debugged through some of the Salesforce SDK code and found that it is failing in the OAuth2 class in the makeTokenEndpointRequest function due to a 400 in the response.  makeTokenEndpointRequest was called from exchangeCode, which is called from the CodeExchangeEndpointTask in OAuthWebViewHelper.  This is with version 11.0.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

Hi @identigral, thank you.  Providing a minimal complete and reproducible example would mean publishing the client and secret, which I do not wish to do.  Also, I would need to start from scratch and write a new Android app for an SDK I don't know anything about.  I think that the question as asked should provide enough information to someone who is knowledgeable about the SDK and its history.

You don't need to publish any secrets, merely the way you're using the SDK. Opening a support case is a good idea.

Hi @identigral, the code in this app is overly complex and has waaay too many levels of abstraction, but I was able to get a minimal reproducible example.  I have added it to my original post.

Also, @identigral, how do I open a support case?  Do I need to create an account?  I tried creating one, but when I get the email to verify and click the verify button, it prompts me for username and password, but I have not set a password yet and there is no temporary password in the email.

https://help.salesforce.com or https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393090&type=1 . Have the admin of your Salesforce org help you.

EDIT 1: Already I feel like I need to add a disclaimer to this solution: This is strictly to unblock you when updating the Mobile SDK version from 10 to 11. Please don't treat this as the recommended way to configure Mobile SDK to authenticate with your Org; there are a lot of docs covering how to set up the various supported auth flows.

I believe the solution to this issue has to do with the fact that Salesforce Mobile SDK 11 now uses OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow by default instead of the OAuth 2.0 User Agent Flow (detailed here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/mobile-sdk/guide/oauth-web-server-flow.html).  The opening paragraph makes sure to point out:

Upon upgrading to Mobile SDK 11.0, you do not need to make any changes in your client application. However, make sure the “Require Secret for Web Server Flow” checkbox is deselected in your connected app.

It sounds like upgrading from v10 to v11 you still have to make a change to the connected app settings in your Org even if your Android project does not technically need any code changes.
Alternatively, if you cannot make changes to your connected app, you can revert to the old User-Agent flow by adding the following line to your app just after you initialize the SDK:
SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(context, MyMainActivity::class.java)
SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().setUseWebServerAuthentication(false) // << add this


Thanks for the answer!I'm a bit confused, though by the statement "Please don't treat this as the recommended way to configure Mobile SDK to authenticate with your Org..."
Are you referring only to the programmatic change you suggest?  Or does that also apply to the suggestion of (I believe) unchecking the "Require Secret for Web Server Flow" checkbox?

It applies to both, and I added the disclaimer as a way to cover my butt when someone comes across this in the future. All I'm saying is that people should not blindly apply this solution as a fix to this specific error since it affects the security of your app. It can unblock you in an upgrade, but choosing which option to pursue should be a conscious choice, not just a copy-paste from a Stack Exchange answer.

Imported the source code for the 10.2 Salesforce SDK release as an Android Studio module and then fixed the invocations of registerReceiver so it would run under Android 34.

Confusing answer because in your problem statement you said I bumped from 10.1.0 to 10.2.0 and could still sign in (and no mention of any dependency on Android version)

@identigral, was paring it down to the bare minimum.  I had backed out of any Android changes and proved that I could not use 11.0 even without all of that.  That is an issue IMO, and is completely independent of the fact I'm trying to go to Android 14/34.
My answer is not a solution, it is a workaround.  Note that I did not mark it as the accepted answer.
